# How to create a agree checkbox before submit:

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I am very confused about how to implement the agree  checkbox using cakephp.

i know how to do in php but no idea in cakephp 3.0

Comment: Please provide the code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

more details in https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-select-checkbox-and-radio-controls

```
$this->Form->checkbox('published', [
  'value' => 'Y',
  'hiddenField' => 'N',
]);
```